How can I lock my mouse in the borders of my game window and unlock it when I click ESCAPE
I want to make my mouse invisible and staying into the screen. When I click ESCAPE I want to unlock my mouse, make it visible and pause my game. Then, when I click my mouse in the window, I want to make my mouse invisible and staying into the screen again.
This is my program:
import pgzrun
import pygame

WIDTH = 800
HEIGHT = 600

def start():
    global exit, playing
    exit = False
    playing = True
    pygame.mouse.set_visible(False) #set my mouse invisible
    #here I want to write a code witch will block my mouse in the borders

def update():
    global exit, playing
    if keyboard.Escape:
        exit = True
    if exit:
        pygame.mouse.set_visible(True) #set my mouse visible
        #here I want to unblock it
        playing = False
        if mouse.LEFT:
            playing = True
    if playing:
        start()

def draw():
    if exit:
        screen.draw.text("Paused", (200, 200), color=(255,255,255), fontsize=60)
        screen.draw.text('Press in the screen to continue', (200, 250), color=(255,255,255), fontsize =60)

pgzrun.go()

I don't have any Idea how to set my mouse blocking in the screen borders.

pygame.event.set_grab(True)    Works but exit doesn't. I don't know why but ESKAPE doesn't work.

Why don't you check if the mouse is inside your window? Always have a variable named recent_pos_x, recent_pos_y and set it to the x,y of the mouse. If the mouse gets out of screen, set the mouse back to recent_pos_x and recent_pos_y. When escape is pressed, stop doing this.

You can use the pygame.event.set_grab(True) function to confine the cursor within your pygame window. To release the cursor again just use pygame.event.set_grab(False).
